# M1 - Remove shipping cost calculation from shoppingcart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

In Magento 1 i want to hide the shipping costs from the shoppingcart view. So the totals that are visible should be without the shipping costs. Only when someone chooses to get the order delivered in the checkout process then they see the radio button with the extra costs for the shipping.

How can I achieve that?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> Way 1

Remove the following code from below file.

> app/design/frontend/your_package/yourtheme/layout/checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

> Way2

Check this and put in your theme's `app/design/frontend/your_package/yourtheme/layout/local.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

after that clear cache from admin side or delete var/cache folder